# Svelte: Not updating #each when variable changes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte

I'm trying to display (and update live) my application logs so I can watch them via the web. The issue is, when I call updateLogs() it doesn't re-render the each, it never does, even when calling updateLogs() in mount for the first time.

Each loop:

```
{#each application.logs as log }
    <p>{log}</p>
{/each}
```

updateLogs:

```
function updateLogs() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/applications/' + application.Id + '/logs')
        .then(function (response) {
            application.logs = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Declaration:

```
let application = {
    logs: []
};
```

Comment: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects *Svelte's reactivity is triggered by assignments. Methods that mutate arrays or objects will not trigger updates by themselves.*

Comment: Check `response.data` - from the logic this should update

Answer (score 1):

Since the assignment was mentioned three times

```js
application.logs = response.data
```

is one and there's no problem with that here but probably with the response / returned data

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/08ad9aaecb484154a112d341dc191009?version=3.57.0)

```
<script>
    let application = {
        logs: []
    };

    async function fetchLogs() {
        return {data: ['log']}
    }

    function updateLogs() {
        fetchLogs()
            .then(function (response) {
            application.logs = response.data;
        })
            .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
</script>

<button on:click={updateLogs}>
    updateLogs
</button>

{#each application.logs as log }
<p>{log}</p>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of 3 ways you can achieve this.

1. Use the reactive `$:` instead of `let` to declare `application`

```js
$: application = {
    logs: []
};
```

2. Use the `key` block to watch and re-render the child block `(#each)` every time the watched variable changes; in this example `(application.logs)`.

```html
{#key application.logs}
{#each application.logs as log}
<p>{log}</p>
{/each}
{/key}
```

3. Declare `application.logs` again just to confirm, works sometimes... I don't know how and why..

```js
function updateLogs() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/applications/' + application.Id + '/logs')
        .then(function (response) {
            application.logs = response.data;
             application.logs =  application.logs //****Added Line
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your updateLogs() function to this:

```js
function updateLogs() {
  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/applications/' + application.Id + '/logs')
    .then(function (response) {
        // Reassigning application with the updated data using ES6 spread syntax 
        application = {...application, logs: response.data};
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
 }
```

Svelte doesn't consider `application.logs = response.data` as a reactive assignment. You can either update the object and then reassign it to itself or use the ES6 spread syntax like I did. You can learn more about it [here](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects).

Thanks!

Comment: a props changed means it changed svelte recognized that and it reacted. error in return API